# Flow Builder trigger for all orders

Tags: shopware6

Edit: Can't reproduce this anymore. `checkout.order.placed` correctly triggers alsow for manual orders.

We just noticed the `checkout.order.placed` trigger in the Flow Builder doesn't trigger for manual orders. I couldn't find an equal trigger which can be used for manual orders.

Does a trigger for this exist? If not, is this a bug or by design?

Comment: Which Shopware version are you using? On the current trunk branch it seems to be working fine and the flow is triggered when creating orders in the administration.

Comment: Currently we're on 6.4.13.0

Comment: Do you usually create a customer for the manual order or do you choose one that is already registered? Did you make significant changes to the order confirmation mail template? To exclude the send mail action as a point of failure could you create a new flow with the order placed trigger and a different action? To test you could use the action that adds a tag and afterwards check if the manual order has the tag.

Comment: Somehow we can't reproduce this anymore. Thanks for your tips!